# SVN: Inquire usage practice

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Our team creates sole bug-branch, from trunk, intended for bugs-fixing; verifying on PROD, we need to merge codes back into trunk. (We don't preferr creating one new branch per bug reported)

**Our current practice** is that using WinMerge compares sb's modification in bug-branch with counterparts in trunk, and merge. However, manual intervention - e.g., find what files you amended - sometimes makes mergence go wrong, e.g., forget files being merged.

I'd like to know how you use SVN or other tools to faciliate the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading this (if you don't know yet): http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s03.html#svn-ch-4-sect-3.3

Comment: I'm trying what u provided, finding that I cannot single out a section of codes in a file to merge. Let's say a file is modified for bugs #11, #12, and #11 is confirmed fixed being merged back to trunk; i cannot merge the section modified for #11 with SVN merge, is it?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean 'find what files you amended'? Simply merge the whole bug-branch back into the trunk using TortoiseSVN. Subversion will know which files you modified in your bug branch and which are untouched.

Comment: is it? could u provide the article about ur recommendation?

Comment: When you merge back, select the root path of your bug branch, not individual files.

Comment: I'm trying what u said, finding that I cannot single out a section of codes in a file to merge. Let's say a file is modified for bugs #11, #12, and #11 is confirmed fixed being merged back to trunk; i cannot merge the section modified for #11 with SVN merge, is it?

Comment: Then your fixing/testing process is broke.
You fix a whole file with the various bugs in it. And *THAT* gets released into Test/Staging and then promoted into Production.

Comment: That is why I am looking for better process/tools. Our developers share the same single bug-branch to fix minior issues. Is is possible to discern the diff between two branches with SVN?